# .htaccess mod rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to write a url from 
Original URL

```
www.xyz.com/folder/articles?id=1221
```

to rewrite URL

```
www.xyz.com/folder/article-title-1221.html
```

Would this be possible? I am wanting to creates dynamic pages based on the id in the url.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A little confused. Which is the URL you would like to *use*? That is, type into the browser address bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 RewriteRule folder/article-title-([0-9]+)\.html$ folder/articles?id=$1 [L]
```